# .net web api single http post accept different resource documents

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

I have a web api 2 basic template and would like to make my controllers POST method accept multiple documents (they differ in data slightly but it semantically makes sense that it is the same endpoint accepting these documents).

Is this even possible with .net web api 2? Would I need a custom model binder to convert the document that was recieved in the request into a consistent object model for the controller action to be selected/invoked correctly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how slightly different your POST request but can you have some pseudo class sample?